# "Guild" versus "association"

Tags: meaning

Is there any difference? Why would you say *authors guild* and not *authors association*?

Comment: English has very, very few true synonyms: if the words are different, then the guidance is that there will be a difference in meaning and/or nuance. I suggest that you look at the history of "the guilds" in Europe and the meaning of the verb "to associate."

Comment: @Greybeard - You have summed this up nicely. People often ask "If A means B, a synonym of C, can't I use ...?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously "correct" usage is whatever [the group in question's] founders originally decided to call themselves (there are also *Federations*, *Fellowships*, *Societies*, *Unions*, etc.)

*Guild* has a somewhat archaic flavour, but a newly-formed group might choose it simply to imply a long and distinguished history. It also has stronger overtones of the members being [traditional] craftsmen with tradeable skills and/or products.

*Association* may imply a looser (often predominantly commercial) relationship between members.

Answer (score 2):

*Guild* is the word used for "an association of people for mutual aid or the pursuit of a common goal." It is then a word that has a more specific meaning than *association*.

The other meanings of *guild* are "a medieval association of craftsmen or merchants, often having considerable power" and (in ecology) "a group of species that have similar requirements and play a similar role within a community." (Both of them don't apply in the specific case.)