# What's a polite term for a cartel?

Tags: synonyms

This question comes directly out of [this comment](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/why-do-non-lawyers-refer-you-to-lawyers-even-when-they-know-the-answer#comment15277_8037) on Law.SE, on an answer discussing restrictions about who can practice law.

> The legal profession is a ***cartel***, protected by laws.

Is there a term that is similar to "cartel" but **omits** what Dawn [describes as](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/8032/why-do-non-lawyers-refer-you-to-lawyers-even-when-they-know-the-answer#comment15276_8037) "a generally [pejorative connotation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cartel) that implies a *purpose* of controlling prices or limiting competition," especially looking for a term which would apply to lawyers?

Comment: Cartel  carries  no impolite connotation,it just refer sto a specific market condition where market participants manipulate prices to some extent.

Comment: @Josh61 What about collusion to restrict participation in the market, without specific price-fixing?

Comment: Collusion refers to an illegal activity : http://www.thefreedictionary.com/collusion - What concept do you want to express?

Comment: In the US, you can use ***association***, as in the *American Bar Association*.

Comment: *Syndicate or consortium* may convey a more neutral to positive meaning.

Comment: @Josh61 Collusion is a key component of the first [definition of cartel](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cartel) that Dawn linked to.  That, combined with your second comment above ("Collusion refers to an illegal activity"), indicates "cartel" carries a connotation of illegal activity, conflicting with "protected by laws."  Can you see the motivation for this question?

Comment: Yeah, no one would ever use "syndicate" to imply some sort of illegal activity. ;)

Comment: (And "collusion" does not necessarily imply illegal activity, if you look at the full definitions.)

Comment: If you want to be "above board" about it, you can use something like "legal monopoly".

Comment: I disagree with @Josh61: the term "cartel" indeed has acquired negative connotations in U.S. English, as a result of its most common usage in the media and general discourse being in the context of "[illegal] drug cartel".  I have even heard it used bare, without the "drug" qualifier, to refer to drug cartels.

Comment: [This book](https://books.google.com/books?redir_esc=y&id=pi7UCgAAQBAJ&dq=cartel+pejorative&q=cartel+pejorative#v=snippet&q=cartel%20pejorative&f=false) supports the position that there is a negative connotation associated with the word "cartel". I think we can take it as a given that at least some people have this reaction to the word and that this question is about finding an alternative word or phrase that doesn't have that connotation, even if *you* don't personally get that connotation when hearing the word.

Comment: Anyway, your question seems a bit inconsistent.  Inasmuch as most people would view controlling prices (to keep them artificially high) and limiting competition as negative behaviors, at least when viewed by outsiders, how would a word that specifically implies such activity *not* carry a generally negative connotation?

Comment: Compared with the collective nouns _disputation, greed, huddle, quarrel_, and perhaps _escheat_, maybe _cartel_ doesn't sound too bad.

Comment: http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/cartel

Comment: Surprisingly, the thesaurus does not give 'oligopoly'

Comment: "Oil cartel" may also be interpreted as pejorative.

Answer (score 3):

The legal profession is a **guild** in the sense of a trade association where all the members have the same interests and that call for levels of knowledge for admission (law school, bar exam). Anyway, they are a cartel.
A cartel is an economics term but also used by Jacques Lacan to describe a closed group of individuals working together on a psychoanalytical issue. 
That said, it has broader usage. There is a very interesting discussion on the broader meaning of cartel as also applying to lawyers.

There is a [book called Overcoming Law](https://books.google.com/books?id=3B0hm35X2JEC&pg=PA39&lpg=PA39&dq=middle+ages+legal+guild&source=bl&ots=PSGq0QIuWa&sig=3H86YBZdez3Vb49lpqzjlQfEgs0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiZvN7mr-TLAhUEzRQKHYHyBhAQ6AEIRDAF#v=onepage&q=middle%20ages%20legal%20guild&f=false) that is all about this.

Comment: To quote an earlier answer on this site: "[The term "guild" compared to "association"] has stronger overtones of the members being [traditional] craftsmen with tradeable skills and/or products." https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18039/guild-versus-association  Lawyers are not crafts people; they are professionals.

Comment: @zeugma "Overtones" do not preclude the use of a word, especially in a context like this one where the entire point is to grab attention. I would say that the fact that guild is normally used for folks that make tangible things makes it a more attractive alternative here, not a less attractive one. Regardless, I think guild has a stronger association with video games than medieval craftsmen these days. http://watchtheguild.com/

Answer (score 0):

The law is not a cartel, it's a regulated profession. That's not an official term, but lawyers, like architects, like doctors, are individuals who are supervised by regulatory authorities (in the case of lawyers, usually a bar association) that can set requirements for entrance into the profession, Continuing Legal Education, and apply discipline, including suspending or rescinding a lawyer's license to practice law. Lawyers are not a unified group and they're not all private lawyers with businesses like law firms.  They are not able to band together and fix prices, as do cartels, which are often illegal. Public defenders, for example, work for the government, as do prosecutors.  They are civil servants.

A cartel by contrast, means:

1:  a written agreement between belligerent nations

2:  a combination of independent commercial or industrial enterprises designed to limit competition or fix prices

3:  a combination of political groups for common action

[Merriam Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/cartel)

Comment: Given that lawyers, as a group, basically control their own "regulatory authorities" (virtually everyone in the bar association is a lawyer), they **do** have the ability to control entry to the profession, "punish" members who do not conform to pricing standards, etc.  This is what's known as [regulatory capture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regulatory_capture).

Comment: This question isn't about *whether* the legal profession or lawyers is/are a cartel. This is about what word would you use to describe most of what cartel implies but not the part about its members restricting membership with the *purpose* of limiting market competition or price control.

Comment: Dawn, In answering question it is absolutely relevant whether in fact lawyers are a cartel. That is the example the OP used, and it's been misused throughout.

Comment: There is no organization of humans for which the term "cartel" is not, at times, appropriate.

Comment: I understand your point about defining why The Law is not a cartel. In order to make this an answer, you should provide an alternative.

Comment: @Kit Z. Fox I posted the dictionary definition of "cartel."  That should be more than sufficient.

Comment: It's not sufficient to explain why cartel isn't the right word. The question already assumes that. You are expected to offer the right word or at least a sufficient approximation otherwise you haven't answered the question.

Comment: @kit z. fox.  I've already explained it. I'm not going to go around in circles.

Comment: @zeugma - So, what ***is*** your proposed “polite” term?